# What is the best way to load script inside js condition

Tags: javascript

I have code and looking for best practice to load script inside the code.

This is how I manually included before - `<script src='//test.test/adition/?'></script>`

If the condition is true, I need to load `<script src='//test.test/adition/?'></script>` in script below.

I have found out that `document.write()` is not best practice, any advices?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isMobile = /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
    var element = document.getElementById('text');
    if (isMobile) {

    } else {
        console.log('error');    
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You should not use user agent to differentiate between browsers or to detect if the site is loaded on a mobile device, this might lead to false assumptions about screen resolutions and about input devices.  You should use feature detection instead.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's an async action you should do it like this:

```
function loadScript(src) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = src;
    script.onload = () => resolve(script);
    script.onerror = () => reject(new Error(`Script load error for ${src}`));
    document.head.append(script);
  });
}
```

Comment: This answer is perfectly fine. But you should avoid answering a question that is a duplicate to an already highly voted question. Instead, you should mark the question as duplicate or write a comment linking to that duplicate. And if the duplicate is missing the technique you write in your answer you should add your answer to that duplicate.

Comment: Sorry I couldnt find the question

Comment: @t.niese im on my phone and i dont know how to do it from the stack exchange app so i just answered the question